Мультибот в ТГ на aiogram
Решил попробовать создать мультибота и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: у каждого моего миньона (бота из сетки других ботов), в БД имеется например уникальное приветствие, которое  бот должен подтягивать по своему идентификатору (например токену). Вопрос в том, как бот может идентифицировать себя, чтобы обратиться по своему идентификатору к БД и получить нужные данные?

А в чем проблема-то? Ну и используйте токен, и соединяйте по нему таблицы в БД

А как в хендлере узнать токен бота от которого прилетел апдейт? Я ведь создаю много экземпляров бота и поэтому хз как бота в хендлере можно идентифицировать

@MyNameIsIvan https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/methods/get_me.html а вообще создается же отдельный файл конфига бота, где может находиться токен, откуда его и можно брать в последующем для сверки с токеном в бд?

@MyNameIsIvan вообще, для aiogram уже есть решение для мультибота https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/multibot.py

https://github.com/MasterGroosha/aiogram-and-sqlalchemy-demo, provide token for welcome handler!

В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
